# VSTS CI build does not trigger

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have configured a build meant to be run in the default queue on a CI trigger with a Path filter. However, even though there are changes to the files/folders under the path specified in the path filter, the CI does not trigger the build.

Here is what the trigger tab looks like:
[image: CI trigger]

As a fallback, I have added a schedule as well, but I need it be a CI build.

Similar problem was reported previously, but this seems to have reappeared after a recent update to VSTS. The solution that was stated previously was to append a * character at the end of the path filter. This is no longer possible after the new update. So I guess I need a different way around this.

Comment: Can not reproduce this issue. What's the result if you queue build manually? Are there any build agent available in that pool? Try again with a new build definition.

Comment: Manually queuing works. I have already created this as a new build. In fact this a replica of one of our other builds. The other build works, this one doesn't!

Comment: Do you mean all new build definitions have this issue? Just old build definitions work fine?

Comment: Yes. The old builds are on a different project as well as VSTS account. There is only one new definition for a CI build, which has this problem. Anyways, I will try creating a new build again. Any clue as to why is free text disabled in the path filter textbox?

Comment: What's the result after you creating a new build again? Regarding path filter textbox, you can disable New Build Editor feature, then you can type text in the textbox with old build editor. (Click profile icon >Preview Features >Turn off New Build Editor> Click Build & Release > Open your build definition.